# Another exception was thrown: type '(BuildContext, int) => dynamic' is not a subtype of type '(BuildContext, int) => Widget'

Tags: dart, flutter

I would like to know why I am receiving this exception and how I can fix it ? Code snippet would be helpful

I'm working on Flutter (Channel beta, v0.6.0, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)

Flutter doctor shows no issues found

Comment: Where and when are you getting this exception? Please update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

Due to flutter updates, functions rendering widgets need to have the return type explicitly stated

Example :

If the function was previously defined as

```
buildPhotos(BuildContext context, int index) {
...
}
```

Change this to

```
Widget buildPhotos(BuildContext context, int index) {
...
}
```